# Remove last dots from characters in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

How to remove only the last dots in characters in jquery?

Example:

`1..`

`1.2.`

Expected result:

`1`

`1.2`

My code:

`var maskedNumber = $(this).find('input.CategoryData');`

`var maskedNumberValue = $(maskedNumber).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace('.', 'x').replace('x', '.').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');`

`console.log(maskedNumberValue.slice(0, -1))`

How do I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [regex replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for that:

```js
function removeLastDot(value) {
  return value.replace(/\.*$/, '')
}

console.log(removeLastDot('1..'))
console.log(removeLastDot('1.2.'))
```

In the example I use `\.*$` regex:

- `$` - means that I want replace at the end of string
- `\.*` - means that I want to match any number for `.` symbol (it is escaped cause `.` is special symbol in regex)

Comment: so many thanks @KiraLT, your code working well as i needed!

Comment: @FannyKaunang  Note that this replacement has nothing to do with numbers, it removes all dots at the end of any string.

Comment: yep, noted! i just set the input to number only to preventing the characters string was captured. thanks again

Comment: @FannyKaunang. In that case the question and the title is not correct for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the string with forEach and store the last index of any number in a variable. Then slice up to that variable.

```
let lastDigitIndex = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   let c = str[i];
   if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') lastDigitIndex = i;
};
console.log(str.slice(0, lastDigitIndex-1));
```

This will be an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `replace(/\.*$/g, '')` to match one or more dots at the end of the string.

So your code would be like this:

```
var maskedNumberValue = $(maskedNumber).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace('.', 'x').replace('x', '.').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '').replace(/\.*$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help.

```js
var t = "1...";
    while (t.substr(t.length - 1, 1) == ".") {
      t = t.substr(0,t.length - 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = '1.4....'
# reverse the string
rev_s =  s[::-1]
# find the first digit in the reversed string
if first_digit := re.search(r"\d", rev_s):
    first_digit = first_digit.start()
    # cut off extra dots from the start of the reversed string
    s = rev_s[first_digit:]
    # reverse the reversed string back and print the normalized string
    print(s[::-1])

1.4
```